# module.js:485 process.dlopen(filename, module.exports);

Tags: node.js, v8, node-gyp, gyp

I am getting this error on a node native addon I created. It works fine on my development machine, but breaks on the test machine.

```
module.js:485 process.dlopen(filename, module.exports);

Error: The specified module could not be found.
j:\node_modules\mhl-dispatcher\node_modules\node-odp\libs\build\Release\odpnode.node
```

In the c++ code, I'm using some dlls:

```
System.dll
System.Data.dll
Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

I am using the /clr option.
Any ideas to what the issue might be?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out the problem, There are two dlls required to run c++ natives on a machine msvcp100d.dll and msvcr100d.dll. The are added by installing the Ms visual c++ 2010 redistributable package. Also for those running 64 bits you would the the 64 bit versions of the dlls or you would get an error.

```
Error : %1  is not a valid Win32 Application
```

Hope this helps others.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Node either couldn't find the file in any location that it tried, or the Object file does not export a NODE_MODULE symbol.